# Do typical system call interfaces allow reducing the size of a file (without replacing it with a different inode)?

Tags: files, filesystems

Is there a way to `open()` a file and cause it to shrink? One can, of course, open them in append-mode or seek to the end and write to cause them to grow. However, as far as I know, there is no method to shrink a file via typical unix-style system call interfaces.

The only way to do so, as far as I know, is by faking it by creating a new shorter file and `rename()` it in place of the older one.

I just wanted confirmation, because I saw an answer that implied that it was possible to make file editors that worked directly on a file instead of going through the process of making a new one and renaming it in place.

I've always thought that the file api in libc and unix-style system call interfaces did not allow for the shrinking of files to ease implementation of filesystems and maybe avoid usage patterns that might contribute to fragmentation.

Comment: Just opening a file with `fopen` in mode "w" (or "w+") will truncate it to zero length automatically.  Or do you mean shrinking to a non-zero size, to preserve some of the old contents?

Comment: Just FYI, `open()` and `openat()` already have a flag for truncating, `O_TRUNC` so technically it does cause the file to shrink - that is, shrink completely - without changing inode. Most famous example of that is `command > file.txt`, where file will be truncated if it exists. If you run `strace` on `bash -c 'true > /dev/null'` you'll see `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666)` in the output. Of course for variable size of truncation you need `truncate()` syscall.  Let me know if you want this as an actual answer instead of the comment.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I was thinking of shrinking to an arbitrary size. I've upvoted David Foerster's answer because it answers a subset of the question, but I'm not accepting it in light of icarus's. I would have taken it as a yes-and-no type answer, whereas icarus's answer already showed that the real answer is a "yes".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`man -s 2 ftruncate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) says

```
DESCRIPTION
   The  truncate()  and  ftruncate()  functions cause the regular file
   named by path or referenced by fd to be truncated to a size of precisely
   length bytes.
```

...

```
CONFORMING TO
   POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008, 4.4BSD, SVr4 (these calls first appeared in 4.2BSD).
```

it goes on to say that if you use ftruncate you must have opened the file for writing, and if you use truncate the file must be writable.

Comment: Appending to a file causes the OS to first `truncate` it to accommodate for the new file size, and _then_ `write` it. So `truncate` is the system call you're looking for.

Comment: On Linux, see also `fallocate(FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE)`

Answer (score 2):

The [`open(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) system call accepts the `O_TRUNC` flag that can  reduce file size:

> `O_TRUNC` – If the file exists and is a regular file, and the file is successfully opened `O_RDWR` or `O_WRONLY`, its length shall be truncated to 0, and the mode and owner shall be unchanged. It shall have no effect on FIFO special files or terminal device files. Its effect on other file types is implementation-defined. The result of using `O_TRUNC` without either `O_RDWR` or `O_WRONLY` is undefined.

It is frequently used when the program aims to overwrite the content of a file entirely. An example is your shell’s file redirection operator as in `command > file`.